# asp.net mvc on upload make thumb image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

On image upload I want to make copy of that image save with different name and resize dimensions.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase photo)
{
    string path =  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["propertyPhotoPath"].ToString(); 
    if ((photo != null) && (photo.ContentLength > 0))
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(photo.FileName);
        var pathToSaveOnHdd = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(path), fileName);
        string dbPhotoPath = string.Format("{0}{1}", path, fileName);
    }
... 
//        to do: make image copy, change dimensions
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy a file you could use the [`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx) method. To resize an image, there are many techniques including GDI+, WIC, WPF (here's an example in a [`similar post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11138086/29407)) or a NuGet such as [`ImageResizer`](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfWeek11ImageResizerEnablesCleanClearImageResizingInASPNET.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the uploaded file into byte from the ActionController and change the size of stream as shown below

> Byte[] image1 = new Byte[photo.ContentLength - 1];
>                   HttpPostedFileBase file = photo.PostedFile;
>                   file.InputStream.Read(image1, 0, file.ContentLength - 1);
>                   System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(image1);

and you can use the  graphic class to redraw the image with the desired size as shown below
System.Drawing.Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);

> Graphic graphic = Graphics.FromImage(image); 
>   graphic.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);