# How do I resize an image to fill the new dimensions?

Tags: c#, image

I am trying to stretch an image to fit new dimensions, but I am not being able to figure out how to make the image to fill the new dimensions, it only creates a larger image size but it keeps the image untouched, I want the image to fill width and height specified.

```
 private Bitmap resizeImage(Image image, int width, int height, float HorizontalResolution, float VerticalResolution)
        {

            Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);

            Bitmap destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

            destImage.SetResolution(HorizontalResolution, VerticalResolution);

            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
            {
                graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

                using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
                {
                    wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
                    graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
                }
            }

            return destImage;
        }
```

Comment: What are `image.Width`, `image.Height`, `width`, `height`?  Can you show the result you are actually getting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image resizing using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137979/image-resizing-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @BenVoigt `image.Width` and `image.Height` are the original image dimensions, `width` and `height` are the new dimensions. If you try to run this piece of code on any image and then open the image in `paint` you will see the dimensions are right but the image doesn't fill all the dimensions in the canvas, it appears only to grow proporcionate at some level.

Comment: It was already clear what they represent, but what are their actual (numeric) values?

Comment: @OlivierRogier I looked the accepted answer given in the link provided and same results, no difference at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although none of the answers worked for me, I appreciate all the help and suggestions on which I could get to a solution pretty fast,  here is the piece of code that worked for me:

```
private Bitmap resizeImage(Image image, int width, int height, float HorizontalResolution, float VerticalResolution)
{
    Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    Bitmap destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

    destImage.SetResolution(HorizontalResolution, VerticalResolution);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
    {
         graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
         graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
         graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
         graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;


         //drawImage must be set this way to get the desired outcome
         graphics.DrawImage(imageBox.Image, new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), destRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }

    return destImage;
}
```

Basically I removed the `wrapMode` code and changed my `drawImage` method.

Comment: What is 'imageBox' please?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to stretch the entire source image to a specified size, just use the simple five-argument overload that doesn't accept source coordinates:

- [`DrawImage(Image, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Drawing_Graphics_DrawImage_System_Drawing_Image_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Like so:

```
graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
```

Comment: Not sure if you tested with some image or not, but I did as instructed and remained the same, I erased the `wrapMode` block. What happens is: the image is created with the specified width and height, but for some reason it doesn't fill the whole dimensions, it appears to grow proporcionate to the width and height, but I need to fit the whole space without background.

Comment: @Felipe: Are you saying that it is scaling with aspect ratio maintained and you want it to stretch to a new aspect ratio?  (I'm pretty sure this function call does perform stretching without preserving aspect ratio, however)

Comment: @Felipe: Are you trying to remove empty space that is present in the original image?

Comment: maybe you are right I will try to remove the white space from the original image.

Comment: @Filipe: If there is white space inside `image.Width` and `image.Height`, it doesn't get treated any different from the rest of the picture.  In the `DrawImage` call I suggest, it has no way to know that you want to discard empty areas, and it the one in your question, you are specifically telling it what rectangle of the source image to stretch out and including the white space in the rectangle that you gave it.  You would have to give it a rectangle that defines the "important" part of your image... then that part will fill the destination region.

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw your image with the newer `width` and `height`. It will look like this:

```
  graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, destRect.Width, destRect.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
```

Comment: I made the changes and instead of making my image to stretch, it made 4 copies/duplicates one in each corner of the canvas.

Comment: @Felipe: What did you think that `TileFlipXY` meant?

Comment: @BenVoigt yes I tried without the ```wrapMode``` , no copies/duplicates, but the image continues to not stretch to fit dimensions.